# How to iterate list of map and find max of a field and remove other

Tags: java, list, dictionary

How to iterate a list of map and find max of a field

I have a list with in that there is a map

`listGrid={{id=5,name="person",no=9},{id=6,name="person",no=19},{id=6,name="jam",no=10}}`

I want the result div as it should remove the duplicate of ids and having which is have maximum of no field

```
    List<Map> listGrid=new ArrayList<Map>();
    Map<String,Object> resultMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
    resultMap.put("id", "5");
    resultMap.put("name", "one");
    resultMap.put("no", 1);
    listGrid.add(resultMap);
    resultMap.put("id", "5");
    resultMap.put("name", "one");
    resultMap.put("no", 11);
    listGrid.add(resultMap);
    resultMap.put("id", "1");
    resultMap.put("name", "one");
    resultMap.put("no", 5);

    List list=new ArrayList();
     Map  mapList=new HashMap();
       ListIterator litr = listGrid.listIterator(); 
        while(litr.hasNext()) {

            Map element = (Map)litr.next(); 
            String id= (String) element.get("id");
            Integer damagesNo = (Integer) element.get("no");
            if(mapList.containsKey(id)){
            Integer mapCode = (Integer) mapList.get(id);
            int damagesNoInt = damagesNo;
            int mapCodeInt = mapCode;
            if(damagesNoInt <= mapCodeInt){
                int i=litr.nextIndex()-1;
                list.add(i);
            }
            else{
                mapList.put(id, damagesNo);

            }}
            else{
                mapList.put(id, damagesNo);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(listGrid);
```

I tried with this but it is not working properly.

Comment: Define *"Not Working Properly"*. What are you getting as an output?

Comment: Please mention clearly what you want as output.

Comment: So you want list={{id=5,name="person",no=9},{id=6,name="person",no=19}} as output??

Comment: I suggested a bit other way to solve this. Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515630/how-to-iterate-list-of-map-and-find-max-of-a-field-and-remove-other/11517040#11517040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me you should make DTO class object for your id,no,name values and do processing on them that would be an proper approach

Try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<Map> listGrid = new ArrayList<Map>();

        Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        resultMap.put("id", "5");
        resultMap.put("name", "person");
        resultMap.put("no", 9);
        listGrid.add(resultMap);
        resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        resultMap.put("id", "6");
        resultMap.put("name", "person");
        resultMap.put("no", 19);
        listGrid.add(resultMap);
        resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        resultMap.put("id", "6");
        resultMap.put("name", "jam");
        resultMap.put("no", 21);
        listGrid.add(resultMap);
        resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        resultMap.put("id", "6");
        resultMap.put("name", "jam");
        resultMap.put("no", 21);
        listGrid.add(resultMap);
        List<Map> destListGrid = new ArrayList<Map>();
        HashMap<String, Object> destMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        ListIterator litr = listGrid.listIterator();
        while (litr.hasNext()) {

            HashMap<String, Object> element = (HashMap<String, Object>) litr
                    .next();
            String id = (String) element.get("id");
            Integer damagesNo = (Integer) element.get("no");
            if (destMap.containsKey(id)) {
                Integer mapCode = (Integer) destMap.get(id);
                if (mapCode <= damagesNo) {
                    destMap.remove(id);
                    destMap.put(id, damagesNo);
                }
            } else {
                destMap.put(id, damagesNo);
            }
        }

        for (Map map : listGrid) {

            if (destMap.containsKey(map.get("id"))
                    && destMap.get(map.get("id")) == map.get("no")) {
                            destMap.remove(map.get("id"));  
                destListGrid.add(map);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(destListGrid);
    }
```

Comment: not working for if we have same no like it you put id=6 and no=21 more then one time

Comment: i am also trying


if (destMap.containsKey(map.get("id"))
                    && destMap.get(map.get("id")) == map.get("no")) {
             /*destListGrid.listIterator();
              while (litr.hasNext()) {
               Map mapTemp=(Map) litr.next();
               if(mapTemp.get("id")!=destMap.get(map.get("id")))
                 destListGrid.add(map);
              }*/
            }

Comment: If you find this answer as correct please mark it as an answer so others can refer to it.

Comment: Please take a look at the solution I suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515630/how-to-iterate-list-of-map-and-find-max-of-a-field-and-remove-other/11517040#11517040

Comment: @ViktorStolbin You solution is quite good, that is what I have mentioned on the start of this answer. I have provided solution based on given code by rectifying errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the other way only if it suitable for you. This solution based on creating dedicated class with `hashCode` and `equals` methods overriden that allows standard data structures to work on you. You need hashCode to return id value of your entity and equals method to compare id for equality and compare no value for grater than to allow only entities with greater value to replace the former ones. See the code plz:

```
public class MapList {

static class Entity {

    int id;
    String name;
    int no;

    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Entity) {
            Entity entity = (Entity) o;
            return id == entity.id && entity.no >= no;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Entity(int id, String name, int no) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.no = no;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[id=%d,name='%s',no=%d]", id, name, no);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Entity> initialList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    initialList.add(new Entity(5, "person", 9));
    initialList.add(new Entity(6, "person", 19));
    initialList.add(new Entity(6, "jam", 10));
    System.out.println(initialList);
    Set<Entity> magicCleanSet = new HashSet<Entity>();
    magicCleanSet.addAll(initialList);
    System.out.println(magicCleanSet);
}
```

}

The output is:

```
[[id=5,name='person',no=9], [id=6,name='person',no=19], [id=6,name='jam',no=10]]
[[id=5,name='person',no=9], [id=6,name='person',no=19]]
```

Hope this will help and suitable for your task.