# Java Remove common elements between 2 ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Java class as

```
class Students{
    private String fName;   
    private String lName;
    private String uName;
    
    
    public Students(String fName, String lName, String uName) {
            this.fName = fName;
            this.lName = lName;
            this.uName = uName;
     }      
    
    public String getuName() {
        return uName;
    }
    public void setuName(String uName) {
        this.uName = uName;
    }
    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }
    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }
    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }
    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }
    
}
```

Also I call this using

```
public class TestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Students students1 = new Students("xyz","abc","xyzAbc");
    Students students2 = new Students("poi","son","poison");
    Students students3 = new Students("yog","jos","yogjos");
    
    Students students4 = new Students("xyz","abc","xyzAbc");
    Students students5 = new Students("pon","son","xyzAbc");
    Students students6 = new Students("yog","jos","someotherUName");
    Students students7 = new Students("yog","jos","someotherUName2");
    
    List studentList1 = new ArrayList();
    List studentList2 = new ArrayList();
    
    studentList1.add(students1);
    studentList1.add(students2);
    studentList1.add(students3);
    
    studentList2.add(students4);
    studentList2.add(students5);
    studentList2.add(students6);
}
}
```

Now I want a filtered list which would contain only unique "uName" values. Thus I want the comparison between "uName" field of each list and remove common ones.

At the end I would want 2 filtered list for studentList1 and studentList2.

I read about the removeAll method, but it seems to work with List of Integer/String data and not with List of Objects (as in my case).

Comment: Try code as explained here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515630/how-to-iterate-list-of-map-and-find-max-of-a-field-and-remove-other/11517040#11517040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `removeAll` if the Objects in the `List` implement `equals()` properly.

[`AbstractCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html), which is the base for most kind of `List` implementations (including `ArrayList`) uses [`contains()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.contains%28java.lang.Object%29) in [its implementation of `removeAll`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29). `ArrayList`'s [implementation of `contains`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.contains%28java.lang.Object%29) relies on `indexOf()`, which lastly uses `equals()`.

You could implement `equals()` in your `Student` class to specify that an `Student` is equal to another if and only their `uName` fields are equal.

Please note that `equals` has associated semantics (see its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))), and you should be careful when choosing how to implement it. Consider if two student instances really represent the same student when their `uName`s are equal. In my opinion, this sounds like a very specific requirement of how to sort these things out and should not impact the semantics of the class.

You'll be much better off with [@AlexR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11646966/851811) or [@KumarVivekMitra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11646983/851811)'s approach.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the same ? Also in my case, I want the comparision between the ivars of the Students object.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your list to set and then (if you need) to take it back:

`new ArrayList(new HashSet<String>(list))` creates list that contains only unique elements from source list.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** If you want each list to have **unique** `uName` value, then you can use `TreeSet` from `java.util.Collection` along with **Interface** `Comparator` from `java.util.Comparator`.

**2.** If you **want to merge both the list and have unique uName**, then combine both the list and then use `TreeSet` and `Comparator`.

**3.** `Comparator` gives the **flexibility to compare in more than one way**...

Comment: Thx a lot...Could you please provide an example for the 2nd option (merging both list with only unique uName) ?

Comment: Merge both the list first...... then insert it in a TreeSet which has used a Comparator that compares the students with their uName... See these example about the TreeSet with the Comparator..   http://www.javaexamples4u.com/2009/04/treeset-comparator.html ... I am at work now... when i will reach home, i will try to reply back

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should be typing your lists:

```
List<Students> studentList1 = new ArrayList<Students>();
```

Secondly, implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` on your `Students` class that both delegate to `uName`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Students && ((Students)o).uName.equals(uName);
}

public int hashCode() {
    return uName.hashCode();
}
```

Now [`removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) will work just fine.

---

Another option is to use `Set`, which only allows unique values as determined by the `equals()` method. If you add the above methods to your class, you could just do this:

```
Set<Students> students = new HashSet<Students>();
```

then add what you like to it and there will only ever be unique `uName` students in it.

---

btw, you should name your class in the singular - ie `Student` not `Students`.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help...How exactly do I call the removeAll() method ?

Comment: It's all in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)), but it's simply `list1.removeAll(list2);`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the apache commons `CollectionUtils.disjunction`. (link: http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction(java.util.Collection, java.util.Collection))

Answer (score 0):

Your class Student should override methods `hashcode` and `equals`, so youy object can be unique by name. [Here](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html) you can read how to do that.

Also note that all objects which are maintained in some collection should have those methods overriden, so you always know how are they compared.

In next step you can use `removeAll` method or the solution with Set, it's up to you :-)

Set example

`List<String> list = new ArrayList(new HashSet<String>(studentList));` // here is your unique list

Or you could use custom Comparator instead of overriding hashcode and equals but if you want your students always unique, you should override them

Answer (score 0):

A full working solution could be as follows.

```
Class Student{


.....
......
.....

   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       return o instanceof Students && ((Students)o).uName.equals(uName);
   }

   public int hashCode() {
       return uName.hashCode();
   }




}


Set studentList1 = new hashSet();
Set studentList2 = new hashSet();
```

Put your elements in these Sets.

Also if you want unique non-matching elements in both Sets. then write as follows.

```
studentList1.removeAll(studentList2 );
```