# How to remove common values from two array lists

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

How can we remove common values from two ArrayLists?

Let’s consider I have two Arraylist as shown below:

```
ArrayList1 = [1,2,3,4]
ArrayList1 = [2,3,4,6,7]
```

I would like to have result as:

```
ArrayListFinal = [1,6,7]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Try it, then we will help you.

Comment: so you want to remove common elements

Comment: Hint: If you read the api for List you'll solve your problem on your own.

Comment: you can easily get answer for this question if you would have googled atleast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Common elements in two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists)

Comment: @assylias The link you provided is exactly opposite of what OP want.

Comment: @Smit I read too fast indeed - that one is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646913/java-remove-common-elements-between-2-arraylist-of-objects - bottom line being, a 10 seconds search yields the result.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that you could follow to accomplish the task:

- Construct a union of the two arrays
- Construct the intersection of the two arrays
- Subtract the intersection from the union to get your result

Java collections support [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29), [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), and [`retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29). Use `addAll` to construct unions, `retainAll` for constructing intersections, and `removeAll` for subtraction, [like this](http://ideone.com/ijLfd0):

```
// Make the two lists
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 6, 7);
// Prepare a union
List<Integer> union = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
union.addAll(list2);
// Prepare an intersection
List<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
intersection.retainAll(list2);
// Subtract the intersection from the union
union.removeAll(intersection);
// Print the result
for (Integer n : union) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: note: you need to @override equals() for this to work.

Answer (score 22):

You are actually asking for the [Symmetric Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

```
List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
List<Integer> bList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 6, 7));
// Union is all from both lists.
List<Integer> union = new ArrayList(aList);
union.addAll(bList);
// Intersection is only those in both.
List<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList(aList);
intersection.retainAll(bList);
// Symmetric difference is all except those in both.    
List<Integer> symmetricDifference = new ArrayList(union);
symmetricDifference.removeAll(intersection);

System.out.println("aList: " + aList);
System.out.println("bList: " + bList);
System.out.println("union: " + union);
System.out.println("intersection: " + intersection);
System.out.println("**symmetricDifference: " + symmetricDifference+"**");
```

Prints:

```
aList: [1, 2, 3, 4]
bList: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
union: [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
intersection: [2, 3, 4]
**symmetricDifference: [1, 6, 7]**
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon What I have to do if I want an output like [1, 2, 3, 4,6,7] ??

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 - That is the `union` of the `symmetric difference` and the `intersection`.

Comment: I just want the order to be the same. I am getting [2.3,4,1,6,7] or [1,6,7,2,3,4]. The logic I had applied is as folllows             (aList - intersection) + (bList - intersection). And It was working [1,2,3,4,6,7]. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
ArrayList <Integer> first = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
ArrayList <Integer> second = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
ArrayList <Integer> finalResult = new ArrayList <Integer> ();

first.add(1);
first.add(2);
first.add(3);
first.add(4);

second.add(2);
second.add(3);
second.add(4);
second.add(6);
second.add(7);

for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++){

    if (!second.contains(first.get(i))){

        finalResult.add(first.get(i));
    }
}


for (int j = 0; j < second.size(); j++){

    if (!first.contains(second.get(j))){

        finalResult.add(second.get(j));
    }

}
```

I just populated two ArrayLists as you described them in your post, and I checked on both of them for distinct elements; if such element/s was/were found, I add them to the finalResult ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
SetList<Integer> A = new SetList<Integer>();
A.addAll({1,2,3,4});

SetList<Integer> B = new SetList<Integer>();
B.addAll({2,3,4,6,7});

Integer a = null;

for (int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
{
    a = A.get(i);

    if (B.contains(a)
    {
        B.remove(a);
        A.remove(a);
        i--;
    }
}

SetList<Integer> final = new SetList<Integer>();
final.addAll(A);
final.addAll(B);

// final = { 1, 6, 7 }
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.