# match two arabic strings and print the missing words in java

Tags: android, string

i want to make a application to match arabic strings. i do matching in english langauge using splitting.. how do i solve this???

for example:

```
String arabic="الحمد لله رب العالمين";

String arabic1="الحمد لله العالمين";
```

missing word is `"رب"`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755404/match-two-strings-and-print-the-missing-words-in-java

Comment: i need arabic string matching. this is for english.

Comment: should be the same in any language