# String compare with sub string

Tags: java, android

I have taken two string native = "`+8801723519932`"  , and local = "`01723519932`"  ,
how can I compare two `strings` to get `+88` in a `variable` "change" from native. without using `substring`.

Comment: Why "without using sub string"? `indexOf` and `substring` in combination is probably the simplest way of doing this.

Comment: Is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18345060/4762282) what you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract the difference between two strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344721/extract-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, I have finished it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class a {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String nativea="+8801723519932";
    String local = "01723519932";

    String str[]=nativea.split(local);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        String string = str[i];
        System.out.println(string);
    }
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
native = "+8801723519932"
local = "01723519932"
change = ?

**Compare both strings:-** 

if(native.equals(local)){
   System.out.println("Match");
}else{
   System.out.println("Not Match");
}

**Get +88 from given string without using subString.**

if(native.indexOf("+88")>=0){
   System.out.println("+88");
}
```