# String mismatch index

Tags: java, string

I have two strings and I want to get the index where the mismatch happens:

```
str = "abcdef"
str2 = "abddef"

Output: 2
```

So can anyone tell me is there an inbuilt function in java to get the index? If not can someone give me a hint to do so? Thank You!

Comment: First of all remember that indexes in Java goes from *zero*, so the index in your example should be `2` and not `3`.

Comment: And have you tried anything yourself? How did that work, or not work? Please take some time to [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), then [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and of course learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the difference between two strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344721/extract-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "hello";
    String str2 = "helll";
    int indexDif = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        if(str.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i))
        {
            indexDif = i;
            break;
        }
```

assuming that both of the strings are of same length

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step description on how the problem could be solved. I assume that you want to implement it as a function:

1. First handle the case where the strings are `equal`. If they are, return an appropriate value.
2. Next, find the length of the shortest string.
3. Then `for` loop over the length of the shortest string comparing the `i`th letter of the strings. Return the index of any mismatch found.
4. If no mismatch was found return the length of the shorter string.

Hint: The `.length()`, `.equals()` and `.charAt()` methods of the string class will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int myCompare(String s1, String s2){
    int counter = 0;
    while (s1.length() > counter && s2.length() > counter){
      if (s1.charAt(counter) == s2.charAt(counter)) 
        counter++;
      else
        return counter;
    }

    if (counter < s1.length() || counter < s2.length() )
      return counter;
    else
      return -1;
  }
```

If they are equal return `-1`, otherwise the 0-index where it has been found a mismatch.