# Compare Two ArrayLists, Remove items that are matched

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hi I have two custom array lists, I want to remove the similar items from one array list that are matched with the second array lists.

Here is my logic that I'm using.

```
List<Daily_Stock_Pojo> dailyStockArrayListOne = new ArrayList<Daily_Stock_Pojo>();
List<Daily_Stock_Pojo> dailyStockArrayListTwo = new ArrayList<Daily_Stock_Pojo>();

List<Daily_Stock_Pojo> added = new ArrayList<Daily_Stock_Pojo>(dailyStockArrayListOne);

added.removeAll(dailyStockArrayListTwo);
```

Also below one is my custom class used as an Object for the array lists.

```
public class Daily_Stock_Pojo {

    private Date Calendar_Date;
    private int Store_Id;
    private int Item_Id;
    private int Stock_Volume;
    private String MRP;
    private String objectId;

    public Daily_Stock_Pojo(Date calendar_Date, int store_Id, int item_Id, int stock_Volume, String MRP, String objectId) {
        Calendar_Date = calendar_Date;
        Store_Id = store_Id;
        Item_Id = item_Id;
        Stock_Volume = stock_Volume;
        this.MRP = MRP;
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public Date getCalendar_Date() {
        return Calendar_Date;
    }

    public void setCalendar_Date(Date calendar_Date) {
        Calendar_Date = calendar_Date;
    }

    public int getStore_Id() {
        return Store_Id;
    }

    public void setStore_Id(int store_Id) {
        Store_Id = store_Id;
    }

    public int getItem_Id() {
        return Item_Id;
    }

    public void setItem_Id(int item_Id) {
        Item_Id = item_Id;
    }

    public int getStock_Volume() {
        return Stock_Volume;
    }

    public void setStock_Volume(int stock_Volume) {
        Stock_Volume = stock_Volume;
    }

    public String getMRP() {
        return MRP;
    }

    public void setMRP(String MRP) {
        this.MRP = MRP;
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }
}
```

Give me a solution on how to compare two custom array lists and remove all the items from the first array list that are matched with the second array list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove common values from two array list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575417/how-to-remove-common-values-from-two-array-list)

Comment: It seems to me that `removeAll()` should do the job for you. Can you please describe your problem or give an example of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is right. You just have to define properly the `equals()` method for `Daily_Stock_Pojo`. `List#removeAll()` will use the `equals()` to perform the match and remove the elements.

If you don't define a proper `equals()`, the one define in `Object` class is used (all classes inherit from `Object` class implicitly) and the implementation will only check references ([Object java doc for equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))), and that's generally **not** what you want.

As a good measure you should also define a `hashCode()` method that overrides the one from `Object`. This is useful for instance if you intend to use your object as a key in a `HashMap` or as an element in a `HashSet`.

If you use an IDE like Eclipse, there should be an option to *generate* these two methods. The idea is to use the class attributes that will determine *how* 2 objects are identical.

**EDIT**
Following is the default implementation given by Eclipse when using the menu "Source>Generate hashCode() and equals()...". I choose to generate on **all** attributes from the class. If you don't want an attribute to be part of the *identity* of `Daily_Stock_Pojo`, remove it from the methods.

```
   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((Calendar_Date == null) ? 0 : Calendar_Date.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + Item_Id;
        result = prime * result + ((MRP == null) ? 0 : MRP.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + Stock_Volume;
        result = prime * result + Store_Id;
        result = prime * result
                + ((objectId == null) ? 0 : objectId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Daily_Stock_Pojo other = (Daily_Stock_Pojo) obj;
        if (Calendar_Date == null) {
            if (other.Calendar_Date != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!Calendar_Date.equals(other.Calendar_Date))
            return false;
        if (Item_Id != other.Item_Id)
            return false;
        if (MRP == null) {
            if (other.MRP != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!MRP.equals(other.MRP))
            return false;
        if (Stock_Volume != other.Stock_Volume)
            return false;
        if (Store_Id != other.Store_Id)
            return false;
        if (objectId == null) {
            if (other.objectId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!objectId.equals(other.objectId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Note:
You should apply Java convention standards, i.e.

```
Date Calendar_Date;

public Date getCalendar_Date() {
    return Calendar_Date;
}
```

Should be:

```
Date calendarDate;

public Date getCalendarDate() {
    return calendarDate;
}
```

Class members start with a lowercase. No hyphen in class members or class names. Use `CamelCase` (for a class name) or `camelCase` (for a member name).

Comment: yes absolutely i need to create equals() and hashCode() methods. But home to write the code for above object class ? can you write code for equals() and hasCode() functions.

Comment: Yes you can! indeed, in Java, when you define a POJO or _bean_, i.e. an object that holds some data and provides _getters_ and, when needed, _setters_, you **must** redefine the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. This way you can use your object in collections or maps (for instance as a key in a `Map`). I will  post what these method could be in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm that you could follow to accomplish the task:

- Construct a union of the two arrays
- Construct the intersection of the two arrays
- Subtract the intersection from the union to get your result

**Referrence:** Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575417/how-to-remove-common-values-from-two-array-list)

Comment: I would think you need to override equals method from Object.