# Get uncommon item from 2 arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

What i want is getting uncommon items from 2 arraylist

- what i have done :
- code :

  ```
    for (int i =0;i<arraylist1.size();i++)
          {                    
              idNew = arraylist.get(i).get("id");             

              if (idNew.equals(arraylist.get(i).get("id")))
              {
                  newAlert=true;                       
              }
              else {
                  newAlert=false;                       
              }
          }
  ```

-- If **newAlert** is false , get uncommon item from **idNew**

Comment: Help us help you. Can you supply some sample data for `arraylist` and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: dude ,yesterday also, you posted the same question , still you didn't solved ?

Comment: @Mureinik , i need id

Comment: @Amit Ranjan, have u answer yesterday ?

Comment: follow this link you will get the answer [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575417/how-to-remove-common-values-from-two-array-list)

Comment: yes, yesterday i replied to you , i thought you had solved it ,no matters you can see the above link you will definitely find the answer.

Comment: @AmitRanjan [] () not have space in between :)

Comment: @ Pratik Butani Oooo ... my mistake :) thnks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your way of checking is wrong because the items in the two arrays may not be in the same order so you must check if the picked item not found in the other arraylist.

> For Example :   the Class type in the arrayLists is    **Item**

If **id** is unique in **Item** object so you can implement ***equals(Object o)*** and ***hashCode()*** for objects matching

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof Item){
        if(o.getId() == id){
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }


 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    return id*13;
 }
```

> Now you can match objects in the two Array-lists

```
 for (int i =0;i<arraylist1.size();i++)
    {                    
        Item itemObj = arraylist1.get(i);             

        if (arraylist.contains(itemObj))
        {
            newAlert=true;                       
        }
        else {
            newAlert=false;                       
        }
    }
```

> If you don't want to  implement ***equals(Object o)*** and
>   ***hashCode()*** your solution may be as following

```
  for (int i =0;i<arraylist1.size();i++)
    {                    
        Item itemObj = arraylist1.get(i);   
        newAlert=false;            
        for (int index =0;index <arraylist.size();index++)
         { 
            Item item2 = arraylist.get(i); 
            if (item2.getId() == itemObj.getId())
            {
             newAlert=true;  
             break;                     
            }
         }
    }
```