# How to check for a value not in array1 but in array2 in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist

I came across a problem where I need to find array elements that do not exist in array1, however, exists in array2 using java. Unlike SQL, where people can directly use commands "like" or "not like", in java you might need to build a program from scratch. Although, a simple program, it just works. More solutions are welcome!

```
String[] colours = { "black", "red", "white", "yellow","magenta","mahogini"};
String[] colours2 = { "black", "red","orange","yellow","Yellow","pink","purple","indigo","nuque" };

ArrayList<String> coloursExist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> coloursDoNotExist = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    int unmatch=0;
    int max_length= colours.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < colours2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colours.length; j++) {
            if (colours[j].contains(colours2[i])) {
                // System.out.println(colours2[i]+" exists in colours");
                coloursExist.add(colours2[i]);
                break;
            }
            
            unmatch++;
            if (unmatch==max_length) {
                coloursDoNotExist.add(colours2[i]);
            
            }
        }//end of inner for loop
        unmatch=0;
    }//end of for loop
```

Result:

```
[black, red, yellow]
[orange, Yellow, pink, purple, indigo, nuque]
```

Comment: Are you looking to a better way ? Seems you code is working

Comment: you might, but step 1 is always to search to see if something already exists. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575417/how-to-remove-common-values-from-two-array-lists

Comment: @azro, yes, I was looking for a better way.

Comment: interesting solution, never thought this way. thank you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) method of [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which is like a [set relative-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Complements):

```java
String[] colours = { "black", "red", "white", "yellow","magenta","mahogini"};
String[] colours2 = { "black", "red","orange","yellow","Yellow","pink","purple","indigo","nuque" };

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(colours2));
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(colours));

System.out.println(list);
```

*Output*

```
[orange, Yellow, pink, purple, indigo, nuque]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using built-in method `List.removeAll` and `List.retainAll`

```
String[] colours = {"black", "red", "white", "yellow", "magenta", "mahogini"};
String[] colours2 = {"black", "red", "orange", "yellow", "Yellow", "pink", "purple", "indigo", "nuque"};

List<String> colList = Arrays.asList(colours);
List<String> col2List = Arrays.asList(colours2);

List<String> coloursExist = new ArrayList<>(colList);
coloursExist.retainAll(col2List);

List<String> coloursDoNotExist = new ArrayList<>(col2List);
coloursDoNotExist.removeAll(colList);

System.out.println(coloursExist); // [black, red, yellow]
System.out.println(coloursDoNotExist); //[orange, Yellow, pink, purple, indigo, nuque]
```

Comment: Thank you @azro! removeAll and retainAll is pretty straight forward and effective. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
import java.util.*;  

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] colours = { "black", "red", "white", "yellow","magenta","mahogini"};
        String[] colours2 = { "black", "red","orange","yellow","Yellow","pink","purple","indigo","nuque" };
        
        ArrayList<String> coloursList1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(colours));
        ArrayList<String> coloursList2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(colours2));
        
        ArrayList<String> tempColoursList1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(colours));
        ArrayList<String> tempColoursList2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(colours2));

        tempColoursList2.removeAll(tempColoursList1);
        System.out.println("Uncommon elements : " + tempColoursList2);
        coloursList1.retainAll(coloursList2);
        System.out.println("Common elements   : " + coloursList1);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Uncommon elements : [orange, Yellow, pink, purple, indigo, nuque]                                                                                           
Common elements   : [black, red, yellow]
```